# SSIS Error: "Invalid character value for cast specification"

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, ssis

I'm trying to import an Excel file (.xls) with 18 columns; the first row has column names. The file contains 3718 rows of students personal data. This is the error I receive importing the file into a SQL Server database:

```
- Copying to [dbo].[masterlist$] (Error)
Messages
* Error 0xc0202009: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Invalid character value for cast specification".
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

* Error 0xc020901c: Data Flow Task 1: There was an error with input column "dbirth" (121) on input "Destination Input" (84). The column status returned was: "Conversion failed because the data value overflowed the specified type.".
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

* Error 0xc0209029: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "input "Destination Input" (84)" failed because error code 0xC020907A occurred, and the error row disposition on "input "Destination Input" (84)" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

* Error 0xc0047022: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "Destination - masterlist$" (71) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "Destination Input" (84). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

* Error 0xc02020c4: Data Flow Task 1: The attempt to add a row to the Data Flow task buffer failed with error code 0xC0047020.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

* Error 0xc0047038: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on component "Source - masterlist$" (1) returned error code 0xC02020C4.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
```

Comment: Not sure if some errors are direct result of other errors, but I suspect that is likely. However - at least one of your dates for dbirth is not formatted correctly in the Excel spreadsheet. Potentially all the date formats are wrong. Not sure if it expects dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy etc.

Answer (score 1):

These are the two relevant errors:

> "Invalid character value for cast specification"
>
> "Conversion failed because the data value overflowed the specified type."

Your input (Excel) data is most likely not formatted correctly or is invalid.

Without seeing your input file and destination table it is difficult to help, but you should try researching those errors yourself.